# Magento does not put category name in product url when generating google sitemap xml

Tags: magento

How can I add category path to products' urls inside xml sitemap? I have tried to modify the following 2 files but nothing has changed. Which files should I modify?

```
\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\seo\sitemap.phtml
\code\core\Mage\Catalog\controllers\Seo\SitemapController.php
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify any files, but in a standard Magento system the file that generates the site map whose behavior you should seek to change through Magento class rewrites or additional Magento code is located in the following class/method

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php
public function generateXml()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Alan. The problem is that when I modify the generateXml() function, the output xml file does not change at all. Do you know what might happened?